# Combined multiple CSV files to single worksheet maintaining date time formatting

Tags: vba, excel, csv, datetime

So I have been going around in circles trying to find an answer to what should be a basic file combination. 
I have a weeks worth of CSV files generated.
I need to combine the files into a single worksheet with the data stacked
Original file has 2 of the columns that are date and time combined (d/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss)

I have my VBA code combining the data as required but the time formatting is screwed in the master file (d/mm/yyyy h:mm)

Can someone help please with my code :(

```
            Option Explicit


            Sub ImportCSVsWithReference()
            'Summary:   Import all CSV files from a folder into a single sheet
            '           adding a field in column A listing the CSV filenames

            Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
            Dim wsMstr  As Worksheet:   Set wsMstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterCSV")
            Dim fCSV    As String
            Dim fList As String
            Dim fName As String
            Dim fd As FileDialog
            Dim FileChosen As Integer
            Dim FileName As String
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim wbCSVDisplayOrder As Long
            Dim M As Long



                                                        'Select the correct files for merge

            Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

            'use the standard title and filters, but change the
            'initial folder
                    fd.InitialFileName = "C:\RTVis\OT"
                    fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
            'allow multiple file selection
                    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
                    FileChosen = fd.Show
                    If FileChosen = -1 Then
            'open each of the files chosen
                    For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
                    Workbooks.Open fd.SelectedItems(i)
            Next i
            End If

                                                        'clear master page of previous data

            If MsgBox("Clear the existing MasterCSV sheet before importing?", vbYesNo, "Clear?") _
                = vbYes Then wsMstr.UsedRange.Clear

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro

                                                        'Combine files

            'start the CSV file listing
            fCSV = Dir(fName & "*.csv")


                Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
                  'open a CSV file
                    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fName & fCSV)

                  'copy date into master sheet and close source file
                    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy wsMstr.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0)
                    wbCSV.Close False
                  'ready next CSV
                    fCSV = Dir
                Loop

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            End Sub
```

Comment: (a) Are you intentionally overwriting the last row of each csv file with the first record of the next csv file processed?  (b) Is your question asking how to change the format of two columns to be "d/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss"?  Or is your question implying that the csv files contain seconds, but that that part of the time is being set to 0 (leaving just the hours and minutes correct) as you are opening the csv file?

Comment: A) I was actually trying to get rid of header rows of subsequent CSVs and i couldnt come up with a better system
b)  this - your question implying that the csv files contain seconds, but that that part of the time is being set to 0 (leaving just the hours and minutes correct) as you are opening the csv file?

Comment: Try using the `Workbooks.OpenText` method.  It should allow you to specify the format of the date being input.

Comment: Sorry Ron Im not 100% sure what you mean? I tried to modify the line
Set wbcsv = workbooks.open (fname & Fcsv)
to
Set wbcsv = Workbooks.OpenText (Fname & Fcsv) 

Unexpected object error...

Comment: Your problem has two steps: 1) combine several text files into one and 2) import the master file into Excel in the correct format.  For the first part, I would suggest creating a VBScript or JScript script for this purpose and taking care of it from the command line.  Handling basic text files with Excel VBA is adding an unnecessary complication to a basic file concatenation action.  In fact, if you have or are able to install Bash you can probably do this step with a one-line Bash command.

Comment: @Ez_newbie Sorry for shorthand.  I'll post something more detailed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is with the date/time formatting being munged by Excel when you open the file, but the parsing works properly otherwise.

When Excel sees what looks like a date, it will try to interpret it in accord with your Windows Regional Settings.  So if the date in the file is DMY, and your settings at MDY, the dates will not be interpreted properly.

- Workaround 1: Change your windows regional settings to match those in the CSV file
- Workaround 2:  Use the `QueryTables` method.  You can get the VBA equivalent by using the macro recorder and executing, from native Excel, `Data ► Get External Data ► From Text Files`  This will allow specification of the date format.  But you must be careful about not adding them multiple times but by refreshing them instead or first deleting them and then adding them again.
- Workaround 3:  Write your own parsing routine to parse the raw data.  Probably should use the `FileSystemObject` if doing this.
- Workaround 4:  Change the file suffix to something other than `.csv`, and then use the OpenText method. This requires the least changes to your existing code.  You create a new file; import that; then delete it.  The code below demonstrates that process, but does NOT do the other things that you want.

If you use `4`, you should add some error handling in case the file copy / delete process goes awry.  My favorite options would be 2 or 3.

### Sample Code

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim WB As Workbook, wbCSV As Workbook, swbCSV As String
    Dim sFN As String, sCopyFN
    Dim FD As FileDialog

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FD
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "Text or CSV", "*.txt, *.csv", 1
    .Show
    sFN = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

'If CSV, remove suffix
sCopyFN = ""
If sFN Like "*.csv" Then
    sCopyFN = Left(sFN, Len(sFN) - 4)
    FileCopy sFN, sCopyFN
    sFN = sCopyFN
End If

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sFN, DataType:=xlDelimited, origin:=437, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlDMYFormat), Array(2, xlGeneralFormat))

Set wbCSV = ActiveWorkbook

'Get path as string since it will not be available after closing the file
swbCSV = wbCSV.FullName

'Move the data into this workbook
Dim rCopy As Range, rDest As Range

With WB.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rDest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
End With
Set rCopy = wbCSV.Sheets(1).UsedRange

rCopy.Copy rDest

'must close the file before deleting it
wbCSV.Close False
Kill swbCSV

End Sub
```

---